# Receive all messages in AWS SQS queue using boto library until queue is empty

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have a case where a script is writing all unused volume ids to AWS SQS queue and after some time, we need to receive all those messages with volume ids and delete those volumes. Is there a way to achieve this using python boto library?

Receive all messages in AWS SQS queue using boto library until queue is empty

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What exactly is your issue? Please show us your code and explain why it does not work. Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python script should use the boto3 [`receive_message()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message) command:

> Retrieves one or more messages (up to 10), from the specified queue.

Once your program has finished processing a message, it should call [`delete_message()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.delete_message) or [`delete_message_batch()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.delete_message_batch) to delete the message, passing the `ReceiptHandle` for each message that was obtained from the `receive_message()` call.

To process all messages in the queue, continue receiving and deleting messages within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
while True:
            response = self.client.receive_message(
                QueueUrl=self.queue_url, MaxNumberOfMessages=10, WaitTimeSeconds=20
            )
            if "Messages" not in response:
                break
            for message in response["Messages"]:
                recieved_item = message["Body"]
                # Process your item here
                # delete the message from the queue
                self.client.delete_message(
                    QueueUrl=self.queue_url, ReceiptHandle=message["ReceiptHandle"]
                )
```

After you break from the while loop you can delete the queue